# Elements' contiguous storage locations in std::vector and std::deque

Tags: c++, vector, deque

What does "elements' contiguous storage locations" mean with respect to `std::vector` and `std::deque`? According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/), `std::vector`s are guaranteed (and `std::deque`s are not) to store elements in contiguous storage locations. But how can I see it in the code? Both have a random access iterator so in both situations we can add some random offset to random container's reference and all should be ok, right?

Comment: Contiguous simply means the related data is stored in an underlying buffer structure that is more or less behaving the same as a `T data[]` c-style array.

Comment: vectors only have their iterators invalidated on push_back if a reallocation happens, deque's iterators are always invalidated when push'ing back (it's like adding chunked items to a tree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see is by using vector::data(), which returns a pointer to your contiguous data (
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/ ).

You can then use pointer based access to the elements (although, it's much safer and maitenable to use the standard container operations), for example if you want to use a function which expects a pointer or you if you think it could leverage performance.

This member function exists also for arrays and strings, because they also have contiguous elements.

This member doesn't exist for containers which do not guarantee contiguity, such as deque, lists or stacks.

Comment: Note: the main interest of `data()` is **C-compatibility**.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It also makes binary read/write operations easier and adds comprehension, at least for `std::vector<char>` data: `input_stream.read(v.data(), v.size());` vs. `input_stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()), v.size())`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you care is that this implementation detail makes a huge difference to performance. You don't need to prove it by trying to access elements with a pointer, because you can just count on it. A [talk at Build 2014](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2014/2-661) (jump to about 35 minutes if you can't watch the whole thing) showed the amazing performance boost that vector has over other data structures as a result of this memory layout.

Since C++ is standardized, both library and language, you can be sure that `vector` will always use contiguous memory for its elements, and you can count on the speed boost you will get. That's why `vector` should always be your first choice for a container.